# Binding SelectedIndex property of a list to a property in different class in same/another project in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

There is something that I can't understand when I bind SelectedIndex of a list to a property. It works only if the property is part of the Codebehind of this XAML page

for example : If there we have test.xaml , test.xaml.cs and AppSettings.cs , the binding works correctly only if the SelectedIndex property is bound to a property in test.xaml.cs

After some trials , I found that if I set ItemSource and write all binding stuff in Code-behind , it works even if the property is in binder.cs !

I think is related to the order of ItemSource and SelectedItem.

The Code of the Property

```
      private Currency sTileCurrency;

    public Currency STileCurrency
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueorDefault<Currency>("STileCurrency", null);

        }

        set
        {
            sTileCurrency = value;
            if (AddOrUpdateValue("STileCurrency", value))
            {
                settings.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

(This won't work !)

```
    <ListBox  Name="sCurrencyLB" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="180" ItemsSource="{Binding SCurrencyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding STileCurrency, Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Mode=TwoWay}"  >                                     
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock Name="scountryNametb" Width="50" Text="{Binding code}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding imgUrl}" Height="50" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

But if we removed SelectedItem and ItemSource from XAML and set it in Codebehind
(This will work !)

```
        sCurrencyLB.ItemsSource = Binder.Instance.SCurrencyList;
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = settings;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("STileCurrency");
        sCurrencyLB.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemProperty, binding);
```

When I try to set ItemSource in XAML and Binding in Codebehind , it doesn't work too

Comment: What is appSettings and where is SCurrencyList defined? Are we using viewmodel here?

Comment: I corrected names of variables now , appSettings is an instance of AppSettings.cs class and is defined in Resources part of the Grid that contains this list

SCurrencyList is defined in another class called Binder and Instance is a static instance of it 

Yea , I'm trying to use ViewModel (Binder for the mainpage) and (AppSettings for setting page) but It is the first time for me to use it.